# Why won't apache start again when I add a new nameserver in httpd-vhosts.conf file?

Tags: apache, xampp, port

I am trying to change my localhost nameservers and I have added the following code to the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 testingdomainhello.com
127.0.0.1 www.testingdomainhello.com
```

and I have added the following code to the C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.testingdomainhello.com
    ServerAlias testingdomainhello.com
    DocumentRoot c:/xampp/htdocs/sites/directory
</VirtualHost *:80>
```

When I add the  bit however and try to restart Apache in Xampp, it won't restart, and I'm assuming it's something to do with the port being blocked. How do I solve this so that Apache starts again?

Comment: Does c:/xampp/htdocs/sites/directory exist?

Comment: yes, it does exist

Comment: Close the Skype first?

Comment: Skype already closed, I'm using port 8080 instead of 80 on Apache currently as well.

Comment: Well did the system work prior to activating virtual hosts? If not, then skype aint the issue.

Comment: yes it worked prior to activating virtual hosts, only when I add in the code <VirtualHost *:80> ... </VirtualHost *:80> does it not work.

Comment: is my syntax for DocumentRoot correct? Do I need to put it in quotes or skip the 'C:\' part or anything of that nature that might causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bingo that broke it when I used...

```
</VirtualHost *:80>
```

So just end your virtual hosts with the tag...

```
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Actually I found that using any ole document root didn't affect it. On a LAMP system it's the number one thing to cause an error. And I think WAMP does too... Just an FYI!

Comment: Yeah I was having trouble breaking it until I tried what you used as your end tag :)